# Do not run script if user has visited certain page

Tags: javascript, jquery

Any way to tell the script on page x.html not to run if user has visited page y.html? Would like to stay away from the cookies...

Can this be done with session or local storage? On stackoverflow I found only scripts with cookies...

EDIT: Can someone help with something like this:

```
if (there is data stored in localStorage for this page) {
// do stuff
}
```

Comment: __Yes__, this can be done using `localStorage`, `sessionStorage`. You can simply modify the script which you found to be used with them.

Comment: Much depends on the fact that we are talking about anoymous users or authenticated users.

Comment: anoymous users... Will look into that. If someone has some example script please post. Have not managed to find one..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just read the `localStorage` and check if you already saved a visit. If not, run your script (like the `alert` in my example) and save the visit in `localStorage`.

```
var ls = localStorage.getItem('namespace.visited');
if (ls == null) {
    alert("Your first visit");
    localStorage.setItem('namespace.visited', 1)
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zgFgq/

Comment: Thank you, I do get it :) Will start working from this.