# How to get browser forward page URL ,like document.referrer

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, browser

I need forward history page URL, document.referrer it return previouse page of tab, i need forward page URL

see in below image document.referrer it return ("http://localhost/elitemobile/InventoryControlMC.aspx")

[image]

> I need forward page url which is
> ("http://localhost/elitemobile/MultipleSession.aspx") that  i need

[image]

Please help me if any one know how can i achive this
Comment if need more details

Comment: You cannot access the browser history urls. You can only navigate using [history.forward](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API)

Comment: Okay, have any method or API or anything like document.referrer

Comment: No. You will have to track the URLs yourself and that is of course only on your own domain. Anything else would be a  huge security risk

Comment: by using  this i want to avchive if same page load again then do some tasks

Comment: So store in sessionStorage that the page has already been loaded

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24734894/do-not-run-script-if-user-has-visited-certain-page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using **window.navigation.entries()**  get page full history.
In above case we get 4 record 3 back URL and 1 forward URL.

Record like [image]

So from the 4 record now identify the forward URL by using **window.navigation.currentEntry** this will return current page index
[image]
now by using this index you can filter the record by **index > current page index** so this record is forward page's